# How to exclude Mongo spring data configuration only for tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am doing a simple sample project with Spring boot and data.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoConfig.class);
    @Value("${mongo.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
        LOGGER.info(" creating connection with mongodb with uri [{}] ", mongoUri);
        return MongoClients.create(mongoUri);
    }
}
```

This works fine and connects to mongo on startup. However, the tests also pick this up in autoscan. What is the best practice to make sure that mongo config gets excluded for tests?

If I add @WebMvcTest to the tests, it works. But not all tests will be mvc tests. I might be testing a utility class.

If I try using profiles, it gives my an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes: ...MongoConfig`

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Please tell me a repeatable practice as I will be using it for all my tests.

Comment: Read and follow this article and you'll be good: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exclude-auto-configuration-test

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is to exclude your configuration bean when your test profile is active

```
@Profile("!test")
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

 ...
}
```

Here you tell to the BeanFactory to **not** create this bean if the profile **test** is **present**
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html